# Are transient suppression diodes necessary for a battery powered system?

Tags: transient-suppression

I've seen on designs where there is a TVS transient suppression diode on the voltage supply. For example, when the voltage supply is say a wall plug.

However, are such diodes really necessary in a battery powered system? I can't think of any way where the battery supply could "overshoot" the rated voltage.

Comment: When a battery is disconnected, a regulator may go through a period when its output is at higher potential than its input. Many of them require external protection (reverse bypass fast diode) for these events, but not a TVS.

Comment: You probably need ESD protection.  Shocks from human beings can be thousands of volts.  I'm not sure of the difference between TVS diodes and ESD protection diodes.

Answer (score 4):

It could still happen.  Static discharge is one method, inductive switching is another, or perhaps some odd grounding issues bumping up voltages.  I would still use TVS diodes on sensitive components.

Answer (score 3):

If you have ESD-sensitive device inside, it may die when user replaces the battery and touches contacts. Other than that, I can't think of anything.